# how m.quest pass array parameter when using POST method

Tags: mithril.js

something like this:

```
m.request({method: 'POST', url: '/load/users', data: {'q[]': array}})
```

but the result is

> "invalid param 'q[]': empty"

Comment: This looks like a problem with your JavaScript references or your server API. Mithril has no opinion on what your server expects. The likelihood is that when you invoke the request, `array` is empty, and your server API will not accept that.

Comment: 'array' is not empty, when invoke ajax request, it works..  but 'm.request' doesn't work.

Comment: It might be that you are not correctly configuring the `m.request` setup, as the docs say "By default, m.request uses JSON to send and receive data to web services" (http://mithril.js.org/mithril.request.html#using-different-data-transfer-formats). Take a look at this fiddle where I'm configuring the sent data as a HTML form would do it (https://jsfiddle.net/patillades/9p516Lg0/). If it doesn't work for you, you should provide more info on the kind of request your API is expecting and the contents of the `array` parameter